# c# if pictubox is empty then button 2, button 3 and textbox are unclickable

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
{
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    textbox1.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    button2.Enabled = true;
    button3.Enabled = true;
    textbox1.Enabled = true;
}
```

My problem is that when I upload an image in the `picturebox1`, the `button3` and `textbox1` is still disabled.

Comment: what type of application ius this? web windows or wpf?

Comment: ooppss sorry my bad its windows application form.

Comment: What event are you hooking this into?

Comment: @kools Where you call this chunk of code ???

Comment: @kools Added solution in case you did not figure it out yet.

Comment: You need to ensure that your if statement code gets run right after your image is uploaded. Include it in the same method as your image upload code, right after the upload or add it to an event handler of an event that gets fired right after the upload is complete (assuming that there is such an event)

Comment: @J.Tuc Paint event gets fired whenever you upload an image, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run that code whenever the image changes, you could make a method and call it whenever you change the picture or you could pick an event for the picturebox so you won't have to worry about it.

You could use the `paint` event, [it fires whenever the control is redrawn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx).  This has to happen for the image to be loaded so the event will fire when you load a picture.

**Example of paint event:**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
    {
        //Disable buttons
    }
    else
    {
        //Enable buttons
    }
}
```

**For the down voter**
This does exactly what the OP want, paints get called when you change the image.
Example: `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("something.png")` will call the paint event.
So if the OP want to check it whenever the `Image` property might have changed the paint event is the way to go. So if you have a better explaination or can tell me what I did wrong please leave a comment, if not... remove your downvote?

**TL;DR**
Please if you downvote leave a comment that explains it.